# How to use checkValidity with a link button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have a form with a button that is a link (with 'to' attribute) and I'm using checkValidity() to use required attribute, but if I use `to={{pathname...}}` it changes to the link without make validation

This is my form:

```
<Form id="form">
   <Input required /* ... */></Input>
   <Button type="submit" onClick={this.send} tag={Link}
       to={{pathname: '/something', 
       param: this.state.param}}> 
   </Button>
</Form>
```

This is validation code:

```
send(){
   var $myForm = $('#form');

   if(! $myForm[0].checkValidity()){
       $myForm[0].reportValidity()
   }
}
```

if I remove " `tag={Link}`" from button it makes validation, but without changing path

if it has " `tag={Link}`" it change to the pathname without validation

Someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which UI Framework / Kit you are using?

Is `Link` imported from `react-router`? (react-router-dom)

First of all, using `jQuery` inside your react component is probably not a good idea.

You should be able to stop the event if the form is not valid:

```
- send() {
+ send(e){
    var $myForm = $('#form');

    if(! $myForm[0].checkValidity()){
+      e.preventDefault();
       $myForm[0].reportValidity()
    }
 }
```

In your form you should assign a ref to it and use that instead of jQuery:

```
- <Form id="form">
+ <Form ref={form => this.form = form}>
```

and in `send` you can do `this.form.current.checkValidity()`

This is all assuming you are using a class component. In function component you don't have access to ref but you can use the `useRef` hook to create refs.

---

I would refactor this component, and add `disabled={!this.state.isFormValid}` to the `Button` component. You can create a function that updates `this.state.isFormValid` whenever any fields in the form changes.

here's an example of how that might work
https://codesandbox.io/embed/lingering-snowflake-p483o

Comment: How would you do this code with `disabled={!this.state.isFormValid}`?

Comment: yes, it's imported from react-router and thank you it helps me a lot :)

Comment: Hi @CatarinaBatista here's a quick example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/lingering-snowflake-p483o